# How can i exit switch statement and get back to While loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement, exit

So what I am trying is, after I get enough results by one of the searches to go to the other one. In other words I want to exit the switch statement and get back to while loop. How can I do this?

I have this as a code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    String input = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, input witch method you shall use(name, amount or date): ");
    input = scan.next();

    Warehouse storage = new Warehouse();
    //todo while loop kad amzinai veiktu. Ar to reikia ?
    while (!input.equals("quit")) {
        switch (input) {
            case "name":
                storage.searchByName();
                break;
            case "amount":
                storage.searchByAmount();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter your loop you never update `input` and so you do go back to your `while` loop (infinitely). There are a few ways you could do that, one is a do while loop. Like,

```
String helloMsg = "Hello, input which method you shall use(name, amount or date): ";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Warehouse storage = new Warehouse();
String input;
do {
    System.out.println(helloMsg);
    input = scan.next();
    switch (input) {
    case "name":
        storage.searchByName();
        break;
    case "amount":
        storage.searchByAmount();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
    }
} while (!input.equals("quit"));
```

Another would be an infinite loop that you use `quit` to break from. Like,

```
String helloMsg = "Hello, input which method you shall use(name, amount or date): ";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Warehouse storage = new Warehouse();
loop: while (true) {
    System.out.println(helloMsg);
    String input = scan.next();
    switch (input) {
    case "name":
        storage.searchByName();
        break;
    case "amount":
        storage.searchByAmount();
        break;
    case "quit":
        break loop;
    default:
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
    }
}
```

<sub>**Note**: It's [***which***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/which) not [***witch***](https://images.app.goo.gl/Y1bJYhsMmnnvuUkp7).</sub>

Comment: oh nice, i didnt think of using "quit" in the switch itself! Thank you for making corrections!